# Change app from sdk 2.2 to 4.0?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have made an app using target sdk version 2.2 ,but for newer version I need to implement the same app on android 4.0 .But when i tested on the device it shows small layouts.
I have some questions:

1.Why is it showing small layouts ?

2.How I can change it?

3.Will there be any other problem related to this when I switch to android 4.0.?

Please answer these questions?

Answer (score 1):

For change layout

> **In your xml editor .there is combobox for resizing layout check
>   that.**

For Change version

> **Right click on your current project > properties >android > select
>   version >ok**

**no problem for changing**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, you can change the Android target version quite easily. Project->Properties and then select Android and change the target version (Note: You may need to use the Android SDK manager to install new targets and AVDs).

You shouldn't have any problem going from 2.2 to 4.0 although again you may need a new AVD or device to test your app with.

Not sure what you mean about small layouts...

Answer (score 0):

Layout:
Your layout is probably set to a specific screen size or density. To support multiple screens, create a layout folder under res. You can create layout folders for specific screen sizes and densities. Something like this:

- layout
- layout_ldpi
- layout_mdpi
- layout_hdpi

For more info, check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)